# change font only for certain components

Tags: java, swing

I have the necessity to change font style and size of an entire (swing) application, but only for certain components (mainly JLabel, JTextArea, JTextField, JComboBox, JTable).

I have this piece of code

```
public void updateComponent(final Component component, final Font font){
    if(component instanceof JComponent){
        ((JComponent)component).updateUI();
    }
    if(component instanceof Container){
        Component[] children = ((Container)component).getComponents();
        for(Component child : children){
            updateComponent(child, font)
        }
    }

    if(component instanceof JLabel || component instanceof JTextArea || component instanceof JComboBox || component instanceof JTextField || component instanceof JTable){
        component.setFont(font);
    }
}
```

but this code changes the font for **all** JLabel, JTextArea, JTextField, JComboBox, JTable, while I want it only for certain instances of these classes.

I know I can define and create *n* classes extending the original one and check for them, but I really don't like to create *n* basically empty classes for this.

```
public class JLabel2 extends JLabel{}
public class JTextArea2 extends JTextArea{}
...
```

and

```
if(component instanceof JLabel2 || component instanceof JTextArea2 || ...){
```

Is there a simpler solution?
Thank you

Comment: *"Is there a simpler solution?"* Look into the [`UIDefaults`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/UIDefaults.html), or use a custom Look and Feel.

Comment: You can use method `setName` of `Component` or `putClientProperty` of `JComponent`, to put your hint.

Comment: You could also consider providing your own look and feel implementations, but `UIDefaults` is probably a simpler solution

Comment: I don't want to modify the defaults, I want to change the font at runtime.
I like very much Sergiy's response. Thank you all.

Comment: 1) *"I like very much Sergiy's response."* Tip: Add @SergiyMedvynskyy (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. 2) *"I want to change the font at runtime"* It's possible to change PLAFs at run-time. See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) which offers all inbuilt look and feels.

Comment: got it, thank you @AndrewThompson